# Need a mapping of parent and child div ids

Tags: jquery

I have the following sample HTML

```
<div id="page1">
  <fieldset id="groupA">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="page4">
  <fieldset id="groupG">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="pageC">
  <fieldset id="group3">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

I need a mapping of the `div` `id` and it's corresponding `groupId`.
Is this possible with Jquery ?

Comment: what do you mean by mapping?

Comment: In Java we have maps of key value pairs. In Php we can do the same with arrays. Can we have something similar using Jquery.Key Value pair of div ids and its corresponding group ids , so that if I have a div Id , I can use this mapping to get it's corresponding groupId

Comment: i have posted the answer below. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maps of key value pairs

You can use:

```
var result= {};
$("div").each(function() {
 var key = $(this).attr('id');
 var value = $(this).find('fieldset').attr('id');
 result[key] = value;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbzdx8bm/)**

Comment: Thank you Milind. this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: see console for results

```
  $('div').each(function )( {
      $page = $(this).attr('id');
      $group = $(this).children('fieldset').attr('id');
     console.log($page+' '+$group);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all wrap all div inside another div so that you only select those divs

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="page1">
       <fieldset id="groupA">
       </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="page4">
       <fieldset id="groupG">
       </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="pageC">
       <fieldset id="group3">
       </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

and then use this code in jquery

```
$('#parent > div').each(function() {
   var page = $(this).attr('id');
   var group  = $(this).find('fieldset').attr('id');
   console.log(page+" "+group);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by *mapping* but if you just need some kind of association between group and it's parent div, you can try using a `data` attribute.

**Example**

```
<div id="page1">
  <fieldset id="groupA" data-parent="page1"> <!-- the id of the parent -->
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

You can later extract this information and use it to find or perform any operation to your parent.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done

We will create a mapping function using jquery functions :

```
var m=function mymap(mp) 
{
 return $(mp).map(function() {
    return $(this).find('fieldset').get(0);
  })
}
```

now : `m` is a function which accepts `div` and return the corresponding `fieldset`

Example:

```
m("#page4").css('background-color','red') // reference div but actually affects its fieldset
```

Result :

[image]

See here : http://jsbin.com/zakiyo/3/edit